# Prettier plugin tailwindcss not working in the visual code

Tags: prettier, typescript-eslint, eslintrc, prettier-eslint, prettier-vscode

In our project we defined the configs for the prettier and eslint. the problem we facing down below so the when eslint server starting working that will not find the prettier-plugin-eslint but its install perfectly.

[image]

`prettier-plugin-tailwind` package installed correctly but the path the prettier importing in wrong path.

[image]

im using in windows pc and node version `v20.10.0`  so anyone please help to solve this issue.

i want to work the prettier and eslint in visual code. help to find the solution to work the prettier eslint in windows pc